# Ubuntu shutdown instead of waking up

Tags: 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the problem is that, if I suspend it for a long time, then when I typed some keys or click the mouse to wake it up, the system has some react, like fashing of the screen, then shutdown completely, Can someone help me? Thanks very much!

Comment: If you're suspending for a long time then the battery is probably drained by the time you try to wake it up.

Comment: Thank you, but I have wired power supply, the battery is not at all a problem, and by long time, I mean only hours.

Comment: Please [edit] and post the hardwares specs. Also mention, if applicable, any proprietary drivers you may have installed.

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie, I'm wondering what hardware specs and proprietary drivers should I give ? And if there is some command that is suitable for list the info you need?  BTW, my laptop is using Nvidia GTX 960M card, and the nvidia-367 driver.

Comment: That and the model you can add to your question by [edit]ing. One thing is clear now, it's a relatively new machine so, why 14.04? Your hardware may benefit from newer current releases and eventually newer drivers.

Comment: Because I have tried ubuntu 16.*, 12.*,  and have a hard time installing the driver for my graphic card, finally managed to get it work on 14.04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63702/discussion-between-k-wanter-and-michaelbay).

Comment: 12.* is just stupid, don't even talk about it. Now, 16.04 LTS is a valid option and drivers are installed in the exact same way, i.e., by opening Additional Drivers, selecting and applying. The current 17.04 probably even better although the LTS has kernel updates that make it roughly the same as the current release in terms of hardware support). Anything older is asking for trouble, it's asking for the exact problem you're reporting.

Comment: I see, so you think the problem is led by the version of ubuntu being so old?

Comment: I see, so you think the problem is led by the version of ubuntu being so old?

Comment: I suspect it is.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to fix it if possible, if does not work, I'll try to install or update my system version.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet find other solutions, but an alternative is to click suspend in the right top control panel, this way, the problem won't happen.